# Setar corretamente URLS no Django

Tags: django, url

Preciso fazer duas páginas

login e challenge, onde as urls podem ser `domain/login` e `domain/challenge` ou `domain/login/challenge`

Só que da forma que eu estou fazendo está dando `404`

Arquivos do APP: **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def login(request):
  return render(request, 'login.html', {})

def challenge(request):
  return render(request, 'challenge.html', {})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
  path('challenge/', views.challenge, name='challenge'),
]
```

Arquivos do projeto:

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', include('login.urls')),
]
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Lembrando que sou iniciante em python, e estou estudando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você utilizou um include no urls.py principal do projeto, será necessário acessar através do endereço domain/login/login ou domain/login/challenge, caso queira mudar isto, você poderá acessar o arquivo urls.py principal e fazer o seguinte:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from login import views as login_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', login_view.login, name='login'),
    path('challenge/', login_view.challenge, name='challenge'),
]
```

Quando você adiciona uma rota através do include, como no seu caso, só é possível acessar caso utilize o que está dentro do path, no seu caso é o "login".

Comment: Resolvei amigão vlw.